# Alterar escala de x para ir de 0 a 100 mas mostrando as variações decimais

Tags: r, plot

Olá, preciso plor o gráfico que motre as variações decimais no eixo x e varie de 0 a 100

```
fevmt=c(91.9, 92.1, 92.3, 91.4, 91.8, 90.1, 91.8)

a1 =c(91.9, 100)
b1 =c(92.1, 100)
c1 = c(92.3, 100)
d1 =c (91.4, 100)
e1 = c (91.8, 100)
f1 = c(90.1, 100)
g1 =c (91.8, 100)



mt_2  <- cbind(a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1 ,g1 )
mt2 <- as.matrix(mt_2)
rownames (mt2)<- c("Model", "Pereira et al")
colnames(mt2) =c("18 to 23", "24 to 29", "30 to 35", "36 to 41", "42 to 47", "48 to 53", 
                 "54 to 59")


barplot(mt2, font.axis=2, beside = T, ylim = c(min(fevmt)-2, max(re)),
        axes = F,  xlab = "Ages", font.lab = 2,  sub = "Males", xpd = F, 
        ylab = "% FEV1", width = 50,  col = c("cornsilk3", "cornsilk4"))
legend("bottomright", legend=c("Pereira et al.", "Model"),  fill = c("cornsilk3", "cornsilk4"), 
       box.lty = 0, horiz = T, inset = c(0,1), xpd = T , bty = "n")
axis(2, at = seq(floor(min(fevmt)-2), ceiling(max(re)), by = .5))
box()
```

Comment: De 0 a 100 com variações decimais são **mil** tracinhos?

Comment: Além do que disse acima, dá *"erro em barplot.default: objeto 're' não encontrado"*.

Comment: Além disso, `as.matrix(mt_2)` não faz nada, `mt_2` já é um objeto de classe `"matrix"`. (Mas também não faz mal nenhum, é apenas desnecessário.)

Answer (score 2):

Estará à procura de um gráfico assim?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

y_limites <- range(mt2) - c(2, 0)

as.data.frame(mt2) %>%
  mutate(Autor = row.names(.)) %>%
  gather(Intervalo, Valor, -Autor) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Intervalo, y = Valor, fill = Autor)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = y_limites, oob = rescale_none) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("cornsilk3", "cornsilk4")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: essse mesmo obrigada

Comment: não estou conseguindo instalar o package

Comment: @MarianeCampos Qual deles, `tidyverse` ou `scales`? Nota: `tidyverse` é [um pacote que instala outros pacotes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyverse/vignettes/paper.html).

Comment: oi, eu preciso que o gráfico varie de 0 a 100

Comment: @MarianeCampos Tente remover a instrução `scale_y_continuous`.